# How to build a single FFmpeg filter or rebuild only libavfilters

Tags: ffmpeg

I am developing a custom filter following the [docs](https://fossies.org/linux/ffmpeg/doc/writing_filters.txt) and `libavfilter/vf_scale.c` as an example. Does anyone know the command to generate the `.o` file for a single filter or to build just the libavfilters so that I don't have to rebuild the whole library to see how it's working?

Some approaches I've tried are

- Adding `set -x` to the installation script to print out whatever command accompanies the `CC libavfilter/vf_scale.o` print statement. I'm unclear on where to add that and get lost when tracing back the `install` target right to `install-libs-yes`, which has no explicit definition.
- Making a minimal build, though even --disable-all takes
  a minute to run which is not ideal

Comment: Do you want to quickly test changes to the filter source?

Comment: Yes, I just want to generate a new vf_scale.o having only made changes to vf_scale.c

Comment: Takes me just a few seconds to get the new binary. You aren't rerunning `configure`, right?

Comment: You can also just directly build it `make libavfilter/vf_scale.o`

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. No rerunning configure. Thank you!